# Generating HMAC sha256 from JSON request payload in jmeter

Tags: java, rest, groovy, jmeter, hmac

I am setting up a test plan in jmeter in which a Sampler is an HTTP POST request.
I have to send a JSON payload in the request body.
Now, for authentication purposes, I have to create an HMAC sha256 code using a secret which will be passed in the header of the request.
How can I create the HMAC in the preProcessor script?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before with the following:

```java
    public static Mac SHARED_MAC;

    static {
        try {
            SHARED_MAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsaEx) {
            nsaEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```java
private String secretKey; // set this in a constructor or pass to the method below

public String generateSignature(String requestPath, String method, String body, String timestamp) {
        try {
            String prehash = timestamp + method.toUpperCase() + requestPath + body;
            byte[] secretDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKey);
            SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(secretDecoded,  SHARED_MAC.getAlgorithm());
            Mac sha256 = (Mac) SHARED_MAC.clone();
            sha256.init(keyspec);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256.doFinal(prehash.getBytes()));
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeErrorException(new Error("failed")); // fatal error - exits program
        }
    }
```

HTH in some way